# reactJS application with navbar does not right justify dropdown menu items

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a reactJS application which incorporates navbar for navigation.  The initial view shows the 3 line menu icon in the top right hand corner which is what I want.  It looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the menu icon, the drop down appears like this:
[image]

I am trying to get the dropdown to align the menu items to the right, not to the left.  This is the code that generates the navbar:

```
<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul className="nav navbar-nav pullRight">
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.accountinformation}>Basic Account Information</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.contributions}>Contributions</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.investmentelections}>Investment Elections</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.beneficiary}>Beneficiary Information</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.transfer}>Transfers</a>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
             <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.loans}>Loans</a>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
             <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.transactionhistory}>Transaction History</a>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item">
             <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.documents}>Documents</a>
         </li>
         <li class="active">
             <a className="nav-link menuItemColor" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

I thought putting the pullRight in the  classname would pull the items to the right.  I guess not.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get the dropdown to align the menu items to the right,
>   not to the left.

You can use `flexbox` to achieve that layout.

Something like this should work:

```
.pullRight .nav-item {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! @JonathanSmall